# How to search the words in a text file using CAPL

Tags: capl

I have text file say test.txt and I have to search some 10 words from that text file. Could someone please help how can we search words from that text file using CAPL

Comment: What you want is to know if ten pre-selected words are in a string file?

Comment: Yes, i want to search a pre selected words are available in that text file.

Comment: For ex: Pre defined word is "Elephant" then i wanted to search whether the string "Elephant" is there in that text file

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample code to read the text file line by line and search for the expected string using strstr() function

```
dword glbHandle = 0;
glbHandle = OpenFileRead ("Sample.Txt",0);
if ( glbHandle!=0 )
  {
    // got to end of file ...
    while ( fileGetString(buffer,elcount(buffer),glbHandle)!=0 ) 
    {
        if(strstr(s1, "TextToSearch") > -1)
        {
             write("Text Found");
        }
    };
    fileClose (glbHandle);
  }
```